# Using visual studio C++ trying to copy the data part of a WAV file using ifstream::read(). The stream jumps around weirdly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wav, ifstream

This is the first code I used:

```
ifstream wavFile;
wavFile.open("saxaphone.wav");
char buffer[10000];
wavFile.seekg(44);  //data starts at the 44 byte of a wav file
wavFile.read(buffer, 10000);  
//file has more than 13000 data bytes so there should
//be plenty to fill the buffer
```

When I played this buffer with the windows waveOut API it only played coherent sound for about 5000 of the buffer values.

This is the code I used to try and debug:

```
ifstream wavFile;
wavFile.open("saxaphone.wav");
char buffer[10000];
wavFile.seekg(44);  //data starts at the 44 byte of a wav file
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
     wavFile.read(&buffer[i], 1);
     cout << wavFile.tellg() << '\n';
}
```

This output values from 45 to somewhere in the 4000s before it jumped up to somewhere in the 8000s then started counting by 1 again.  I tried different files to see if that was the problem and it does the same thing.  How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to open the file and binary mode in Windows. Also, be aware that WAV files are in chunks so you need to parse the header. There are many variations of WAV files. Sample, Freq, bit depth, and so on.

Comment: Opening in binary mode fixed the problem, thank you.

Comment: A WAV header is not always 44 bytes, it can be considerable larger, depending on the particular format of the WAV file. And the DATA chunk is not always the 1st chunk after the header, either. You have to parse the header and individual chunks to discover the DATA chunk properly, and to discover what format its audio samples are in so you can process them correctly